# Why does J79 have speed more than 100%?

Tags: jet-engine, turbojet

In the maintenence manual of J79 saw this table:
[image: image1]
As you can see, there is speed more than 100% and it looks that the engine can handle it. Can't it?
One more thing, days ago, watched this movie: [flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_(2012_film)). The co-pilote had conversation with the captain about "engine overspeed" when the aircraft was in a dive. Is this related to this speed which is more than 100%? I mean maybe the factory choose a speed lower than the max. speed to prevent engine overspeed when e.g. the aircraft is in the dive.

Comment: @Pondlife: The [consensus](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3969/14897) was there's no need for engine-specific tags.

Comment: @Roh: As a suggestion for future questions, check that such a characteristic is not unique to the J79 before asking, because in most cases such characteristics are applicable to most engines, so a more general and better question would be: *Why do jet engines have speeds over 100%?*

Comment: @ymb1 Ok, but in many cases it's very hard to find the characteristics and specifications of other engines or you don't know how to google your question to find the answer. I think you have been here for a big period of time. For instance I tried to find the manual of JT8D or CFM56 but found nothing.

Comment: @Roh: the built-in search is not as good as Google, but you can use Google (or similar) to search within this site, this is what I did: [jet engine 100% site:aviation.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?&q=jet+engine+100%25+site%3Aaviation.stackexchange.com) – [always search before asking please](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ymb1 Ok, thank you.

Comment: also if any of the suggested linked posts, or the links within those, helped answer the question, it's better to close the question as duplicate yourself, because if not, we expect an edit that explains why those links did not help.

Comment: @ymb1 Thanks! Obviously I missed that consensus :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Various models of the J-79 family of engines have been used on a wide variety of aircraft manufactured in different countries.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_J79#Development) More than 17,000 of the engines were produced over a period of 30 years and used on aircraft such as the F-104 Starfighter, B-58 Hustler, F-4 Phantom II, A-5 Vigilante, IAI Kfir and SSM-N-9 Regulus II supersonic cruise missile. In some aircraft, like the B-58 Hustler, the pilot could choose to override the maximum power throttle stop and squeeze a little more RPM out of the engines.